# Image loaded over saturated (maybe gamut troubles)

Tags: javascript, angular, image, loadimage

We are getting problems loading an image, our trouble is that we are getting over saturated color, let me give you the examples:

[image]

We have checked and the image doesn't have ICC Profiles neither exif properties which could be changing the image.

I have asked to a designer and he told me that it could be due to GAMUT.

Do you you know if is there a way to load the image as it looks in windows viewer?

This is the link for the image that we are getting troubles: 
[photo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10Dql31A7jMA7EYXRGHZTvnnp4vyrgCLo/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks for all the help that you could give us.

We are loading image like this:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(file, 0, 0, width, height);
```

Comment: After a bit of looking around I found [this](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3738355). Have you tried saving the image as sRGB?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @rh16

Now, the image is used to create prints, so while it is uploading to our server we are generating a working image in client side, to allow users edit the image, once that it has being uploaded, we are reloading the image source with the image saved in server which were saved as sRGB or its corresponding icc profile and it will be show correctly, but we need that image looks fine (no matter the icc profile) while is uploading.